# Memcached sessions not reloading the user 10% of the time

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached

I have an old Symfony 2.4 app that does not reload the logged user about 1 time out of 10. I tried to strip down the application to the bare minimum and it is still doing it. Here are some of the concerned settings:

**session**

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: my.memcached.session.handler

services:
    my.memcache.service:
        class: Memcache
        calls:
            - [addServer, ['%memcached_host%', '%memcached_port%']]

    my.memcached.session.handler:
        class: Lsw\MemcacheBundle\Session\Storage\LockingSessionHandler
        arguments:
            - '@my.memcache.service'
            - prefix: '%memcached_prefix%'
            - expiretime: '%memcached_expire%'
```

[`LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle`](https://github.com/LeaseWeb/LswMemcacheBundle) uses `Memcache` behind the scenes to provide a session handler.

**security**

```yaml
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                login_path:    /login
                check_path:    /login_check
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            anonymous:    true
        dev: # standard

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Here is the log when the user doesn't get reloaded and redirected to the login page:

```
request.INFO: Matched route "home" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::DashboardAction", "_route": "home")  
security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session  
security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider.  
security.DEBUG: Username "admin" was reloaded from user provider.  
security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session  
request.INFO: Matched route "AppBundle_home" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::DashboardAction", "_route": "AppBundle_home")  
security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token  
security.DEBUG: Access is denied (user is not fully authenticated) by "/data/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php" at line 70; redirecting to authentication entry point  
security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point  
[...]
```

(I have a redirection in the first controller, without redirection it seems to be working as expected)

Why is my user not reloaded randomly ?
Can someone help me to debug that ?